# How to prevent SQL insert when certain row already exists?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database with different movies, actors, directors.

To connect a director with a movie I'm using a table in which I have the following:

**film_id** and **director_id** - so when I add a director for the movie the necessary id's get inserted to this table.

So I have a bunch of id's already there and it works just fine. For example:

```
movie_id - director_id
10         15
11         17 
9          13
```

Now when I add another director with let's say an **id 9** to a movie with an **id 13** then I have two rows that are exactly the same and that's what I don't want to happen. Shown below:

```
movie_id - director_id
10         15
11         17 
9          13
9          13
```

Instead it should not insert when there already is a row with the same **film_id** equal to the same **director_id**.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: use select query with where clause if it returns any row data is duplicate otherwise insert the data

Comment: Simply make on of these two columns unique. The data will automatically be prevented from being inserted into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the unique key from `movie_id` and `director_id` columns.

SQL example:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD UNIQUE `index_name` (`movie_id`, `director_id`);
```

And then add `IGNORE` for `INSERT` query, it will prevent from the `Duplicate entry...` error message.

SQL example:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table_name` (...) VALUES (...)
```

If you want to update a some data if the entry already exists, then you can use [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

SQL example:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (...) VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `column` = [new_value]
```